# Is this considered functional programming?

Tags: javascript, paradigms

Need some clarification if this is functional, declarative or imperative approach:

```
function sumPrimes(num) {  
    var numbers = Array.apply(null, Array(num))
    .map((n, i) => i+1).slice(1);

    return numbers.filter(function(number, index, array) {
      for (var j = 0; j < index; j++) {
        if (number % array[j] === 0) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;
      }).reduce(function(sum, el) {
      return sum += el;
    });
}
```

Comment: you can remove `;

    return numbers` ... and change `var numbers =` with `return` - just sayin

Comment: That's nothing but a simple function which *return* is implied by it's *argument* use. Declarativ-*ish*? not exactly... Functional? not entirely... etc...

Comment: Mutable variables (e.g. j) aren't all that popular in functional languages. You'd probably structure this to use tail recursion.

Comment: You can't really consider it functional because you are changing the state of variables.